# The tmx map is only rendering two blocks into the screen and all the rest is black

Tags: java, android, youtube, libgdx

[The print from my game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI5rX.png)

I'm learning to develope a game like supermario through a tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8jgD-V5jG8&t=43s), the code that the author of the tutorial makes available in his github is **still working today**, however it is the complete code of the game, and I am still in video class 6, because it was here that his result got different from mine (as you can see from the image).

I would be very grateful if any of you more experienced developers could tell me where I'm wrong to be only showing up 2 blocks of tmx map. I apologize for my english, thanks for trying to help.

The main class of the game:

`public class MarioBros extends Game {`

```
public SpriteBatch batch;
public static final int V_WIDTH = 400;
public static final int V_HEIGHT = 208;


@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    setScreen(new PlayScreen(this));
}

@Override
public void render () {
    super.render(); //Delega o metodo render para as SCREENS que estão ativas.
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();

}
```

}

The PlayScreen (I think the problem is here!):

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
private MarioBros game;
private OrthographicCamera gamecam;
private Viewport gamePort;
private HUD hud;

private TmxMapLoader maploader;
private TiledMap map;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;


public PlayScreen(MarioBros game) {
    this.game = game;

    gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();
    gamecam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2, gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);
    gamePort = new FitViewport(MarioBros.V_WIDTH, MarioBros.V_HEIGHT, gamecam);
    gamePort.apply();

    hud = new HUD(game.batch);

    // Loading the map we made in Tile
    maploader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = maploader.load("level1.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);


}

@Override
public void show() {

}

public void handleInput(float dt) {
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched())
        gamecam.position.x += 100 * dt;

}

public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput(dt);

    gamecam.update();

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    update(delta);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.render();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
    hud.stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    gamePort.update(width, height);
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    renderer.dispose();
}
```

}

The Hud:

```
public class HUD implements Disposable{
public Stage stage;
private Viewport viewport; // Novo viewport
private Integer worldTimer;
private float timeCount;
private Integer score;

Label countdownLabel; // Label é equivalente ao widget, nessa biblioteca gdx
Label scoreLabel;
Label timeLabel;
Label levelLabel;
Label worldLabel;
Label marioLabel;

public HUD(SpriteBatch sb){
    worldTimer = 300;
    timeCount = 0;
    score = 0;

    viewport = new FitViewport(MarioBros.V_WIDTH, MarioBros.V_HEIGHT, new OrthographicCamera());
    stage = new Stage(viewport, sb); // Stage é um bloco que você insere coisas (inicialmente soltas dentro dele)

    Table table = new Table(); // Prender os itens em uma tabela
    table.top(); //  Coloca no topo do nosso stage
    table.setFillParent(true); //  largura do nosso stage

    countdownLabel = new Label(String.format("%03d", worldTimer), new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
    scoreLabel = new Label(String.format("%06d", score), new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
    timeLabel = new Label("TIME", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
    levelLabel =new Label("1-1", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
    worldLabel =new Label("WORLD", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
    marioLabel =new Label("MARIO", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));

    //expandX vai expandir X ao maximo, por isso devemos por em todos para eles dividirem igualmente o eixo X.
    table.add(marioLabel).expandX().padTop(10);
    table.add(worldLabel).expandX().padTop(10);
    table.add(timeLabel).expandX().padTop(10);
    table.row();
    table.add(scoreLabel).expandX();
    table.add(levelLabel).expandX();
    table.add(countdownLabel).expandX();

    //inserir a table no estagio
    stage.addActor(table);

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    stage.dispose();
}
```

}

Thank you for taking your time to try to help me, I already lost a whole week trying to solve this =/ (sad)

Comment: Are you sure your tmx file is correct? Are the two blocks displayed at its bottom-left corner or somewhere else? I don't know much about libgdx, and as such I'd probably play around `gamecam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2, gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);
    gamePort = new FitViewport(MarioBros.V_WIDTH, MarioBros.V_HEIGHT, gamecam);`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help!! Yes, i'm using the same tmx file the author of the tutorial is using and his one works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare your class with [this](https://github.com/BrentAureli/SuperMario) source code of all tutorial.

Comment: I already did, but still he didn't need the full code for making the scene appear and that is all i'm trying to do, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @RenanMariani try to copy only snippet that you have written already. Sometimes it worked fine for me.